# Get type for an object's values where each object is of type <string,function>, and each function have different argument

Tags: javascript, typescript, web

The object looks like this

```
export const templates = {
  [EventType.EventType1 + OutputSources.Email]: (params: { documentName: string; link: string }) => {
    return "some html data";
  },
  [EventType.EventType2 + OutputSources.Email]: (params: { documentName: string }) => {
    return "some html data";
  },
  [EventType.EventType1 + OutputSources.Notification]: (params: { documentName: string }) => {
    return "some html data";
  },
} as const;
```

I want to have a type that contains parameters of each of these function as a union, for example the result for above will look like.
`type possibleFunctionArgs = {documentName:string,link:string} | {documentName:string}`

What I've already tried and failed
`type lastFailingAttemptToGetTypes = Parameters<typeof templates[keyof typeof templates]>`
For the above code I'm always getting only {documentName:string,link:string} , always getting the one with highest number of parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that to work you need your keys to be *constant* strings
If your EventType.EventType1, etc are constants, you may use template strings to merge their type

```
export const templates = {
  [`${EventType.EventType1}${OutputSources.Email}`]: (params: { documentName: string; link: string }) => {
    return "some html data";
  },
  [`${EventType.EventType2}${OutputSources.Email}`]: (params: { documentName: string }) => {
    return "some html data";
  },
  [`${EventType.EventType1}${OutputSources.Notification}`]: (params: { documentName: string }) => {
    return "some html data";
  },
} as const;
type A = typeof templates
//   ^?
type B = A[keyof A]
//   ^?
type C = Parameters<B>[0]
//   ^?
```

Comment: That's the thing, the keys are not constant. They were originally a mixture of two enums, I tried converting the enums into const objects, but still, it doesn't work. Is there any way this could work with the syntax I mentioned

Comment: Also jus to clarify what you said is true, if the keys of this templates object were constant string without square brackets, it works

Comment: @AashishPeepra please make an example with enums in https://typescriptlang.org/play